# Pass number of days to adddays fucntion in azure pipeline dynamically

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Trying to pass the numberofdays to subtract from the date dynamically in the azure pipeline as below:

@{concat(adddays(formatdatetime(pipeline().parameters.StartDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'),-item().Prop_3),' ',item().Prop_2)}

The Variable item().Prop_3 has value like 1, 2  The value is reading from ForLoop.

The above expression says Unrecognized expression: -item().Prop_3

Comment: You could try multiplying it by -1 instead. "mul(item().Prop_3, -1)". Or you could use the getPastTime function instead of addDays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the '-item().Prop_3', the dynamic content doesn't support this negative number expression. @Joel Cochran is correct, you can use `mul(item().Prop_3, -1)` to convert it to the negative number:

Please try:

```
@{concat(adddays(formatdatetime(pipeline().parameters.StartDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'),mul(item().Prop_3, -1),' ',item().Prop_2)}
```

I made an example you can reference:
[image]

The error is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I worked after slight modification as @{adddays(WindowsStartDate,mul(-1,int(val)))}